# finding expectation in circular arrangements

Tags: probability

i have trouble in solving the following question
5 men and 5 women have to be seated in a circular arrangement.find the expected number of women seated next to at least one man.
what should be the correct way to proceed in such problems?
thank you

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/q/167323/129458

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call the women $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$.

Let $X_i=1$ if the woman named $i$ is seated next to at least one man, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise.

We want $E(X_1+\cdots+X_5)$, which by linearity of expectation is $E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_5)$.

To find $E(X_i)$, calculate $\Pr(X_i=1)$. It is easier to first find the probability that $X_i=0$. Suppose woman $i$ is the first to be seated. What is the probability that both of her neighbours are women?

**Remark:** Note that we can use exactly the same method if there are $w$ women and $m$ men.

The method of *indicator random variables* can be quite useful. It bypasses the sometimes very difficult problem of finding the probability distribution of the random variable whose expectation we are seeking.

Comment: I would add that the number of women sitting next to at least one man can be a small as $2$ but not smaller, and can be as large as $5$ but not larger.  Therefore the expected value must be bigger than $2$ and smaller than $5$.  Hence any answer not consistent with that is mistaken.

Comment: thank you so much all of you.that was really helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. That is what MSE is about.