# placing men and women around a table question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can you place $5$ women and $5$ men around a table in a way that $2$ people from the same gender would not sit next to each other?

I'm not sure if its $5!$ or $5! \cdot 4$.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158982/circular-permutation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $5!\cdot4!$ ways. In general, there are $n!\cdot(n-1)!$ ways of arranging $n$ number of males and $n$ number of females around a table such that sexes alternate.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2\times5!\cdot4!$?

Comment: I basically thought there exist 2 patterns, but actually just one, thats why the 2.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach (For those who are bad at combinatrics like me ! :))

There exist 2 patterns

Pattern 1 : $MFMFMFMFMF$

Pattern 2 : $FMFMFMFMFM$

Since this is a non numbered round table, that is chairs are not numbered. Both of the pattern are the same.

5 males can sit on any of the odd position, you can rotate 5 objects at 5 places in $5!$ ways. 
Including what the females can sit Keeping one fixed(for the alternate) and rotating 4 others, no of ways is 4!

Total No of ways for : $5!\cdot4!$

Answer (score 0):

Fix the position of one male person.Now relative to this person the remaining 4 male persons can be arranged in 4! ways. There are in total five spots in between the 5 male persons (1 spot between 2 male persons, and since they are sitting in a circle, there are 5 spots in total). Arrange the 5 female persons in these 5 spots in 5! ways.
Therefore the total number of arrangements possible are 4!*5!.

Answer (score 0):

So first you can make either all the men or all the women sit first around the table; let's say first all the women sit around the table: number of ways of arranging the women = 5!/5 = 4! (we divide by 5 to eliminate some identical cases as you might know)

Next, since we do not want the people of same gender to sit together, we need to place the men in the gaps between the women already sat around the table : so number of gaps created between 5 women around a table=5 , so we can arrange these 5 men in these 5 places= 5! ( Since the arrangement is unique now, we don't use 5!/5)

So your final answer would be 4!. 5!