# In how many ways can we arrange $7$ men and $7$ women around a circular table if $2$ people of the same gender must not sit across each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways can we arrange $7$ men and $7$ women around a circular table if $2$ people of the same gender must not sit across each other?

I think inclusion-exclusion formula should be used, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [placing men and women around a table question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187998/placing-men-and-women-around-a-table-question)

Comment: This forum requires you to first show us what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: i think inclusion-exclusion formula should be used, but i don't know how to use it

Comment: @PerryKleinhenz  This is a much more difficult question than the question to which you linked.